# Anscombe and log transform

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I am trying to understand in layman's terms how the anscombe transform converts a poisson distribution into a normal distribution. So, why is a log transform not sufficient in its own to obtain the normal distribution.

I understand that anscombe transform performs a variance stabilization. Is this somewhat similar to applying a z-score transform/standardisation, such that variance tends to 1 or constant? Is it such that log transform on its own is not able to produce a stable enough variance even though the distribution become normal?

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535593/anscombe-transform-vs-log-transform where I have replied